# VARCHAR TIME TO GET THE DIFFERENCE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I already spent a day looking for the right SQL script just to get the difference of the 2 varchar times.

Here are the varchar columns with each value:

- ProcSchedTime(1319) which is 13:19
- PtEntersRoomTime(0930) which is 09:30

So it will gonna be like this: ProcSchedTime - PtEntersRoomTime = 221 (mins
)
I want the result would be 221 in minutes, not 389.

SQL 2005 here.

Im sorry for the confusion.

Please and thank you!

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question? I understand that you are trying to convert a varchar into a time value but the numbers you are mentioned dont make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the difference in mins:

(13 - 09) * 60 + (19 - 30)

```
select (left(varchartime1,
             2
            ) - left(varchartime2,
                     2
                    )
       ) * 60 + (right(varchartime1,
                       2 
                      ) - right(varchartime2,
                                2
                               )
                )
```

Hopefully it won't throw type errors

Comment: (cast(left(PtEntersRoomTime,2) as int) - cast(left(ProcSchedTime,2) as int)) * 60 + (cast(right(PtEntersRoomTime,2) as int) - cast(right(ProcSchedTime,2) as int))

Answer (score 1):

You could make it look like a date time, cast it to a datetime, then use DateDiff

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,cast(STUFF('1319', 3, 0, ':') as datetime) , cast(STUFF('0930', 3, 0, ':') as datetime))
```

The STUFF function is just adding a colon in the middle.

Comment: +1 The statement works but I want to use the column name instead of the actually value. Remeber that the columns are all varchar. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Duke0ne This answer should work just as well if you just put the column name in.

Answer (score 0):

This would grab the fields from a table,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LEFT(PtEntersRoomTime, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(PtEntersRoomTime, 2)
                      , LEFT(ProcSchedTime, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(ProcSchedTime,2)
               ) AS [TimeDifference]
  FROM TableName
```